# Showing File Name Hint - Active Admin & Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, activeadmin

I am using Active Admin alone with the Paperclip gem to save documents. I've noticed that when I go back into the edit view, whilst the placeholders are there for the documents, it says 'no file selected'. I would like it to show the current file name as a hint.

I've read that I can pass the hint parameter to the input method but all combinations I try keep resulting in an error.

I've tried using object.document.url etc.

All i've been able to work out is that when I call objects.documents I get the active record association, but then no looping is occurring to give me access to the actual document and thus the URL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    f.inputs do
      f.has_many :documents, allow_destroy: true do |a|
        a.input :document, hint: 'What goes here'
      end
    end
```

Full form code.

```
form  multipart: true do |f|
 tabs do
  tab 'Debt Details' do
    f.inputs 'Debt Details' do
      input :status, as: :select, collection: Debt.acceptable_statuses
      input :stage, as: :select, collection: Debt.acceptable_stages
      input :amount
      input :amount_due
      input :invoice_issued
      input :invoice_date, as: :datepicker
      input :debtor
      input :creditor
      input :notes
    end
  end
  tab 'Debt Documents' do
    f.inputs do
      f.has_many :documents, allow_destroy: true do |a|
        a.input :document, hint: 'What goes here'
      end
    end
  end
  actions
end
```

end # Form

Comment: Try `a.object.url` . When you're looping the documents the object is stored as `a` in your code.

Comment: Does't work unfortunately. A is the form builder object.

Comment: `a.object.try(:file_identifier)` will work for you, cheers